# is there a method to delete rows from datframe based on condition?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

hello i have a dataframe :

```
name; id ; firstname ;lastname
MD ALEXIA DORTMINEX ; 1; ALEXIA ; DORTMINEX
DOC PAULO RODRIGEZ ; 3 ; PAOLO ; SANCHEZ
```

i want to keep only rows if name contains lastname (i.e lastname is in name)

in our case , we keep only:

```
name; id ; firstname ;lastname
MD ALEXIA DORTMINEX ; 1; ALEXIA ; DORTMINEX
```

because DORTMINEX is in MD ALEXIA DORTMINEX

thnks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I select rows from a DataFrame based on column values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-do-i-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply` and slicing:

```
df[df.apply(lambda r: r['lastname'] in r['name'], axis=1)]
```

output:

```
                  name  id firstname   lastname
0  MD ALEXIA DORTMINEX   1    ALEXIA  DORTMINEX
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether your lastname column contains your name column using a `list` comprehension which will return a boolean (`True / False`). Placing it within `loc` will filter your dataframe using the resulting boolean, which will give you what you require:

```
>>> [name[0] in name[1] for name in zip(df['lastname'], df['name'])]

[True, False]
```

---

```
>>> df.loc[[name[0] in name[1] for name in zip(df['lastname'], df['name'])]]

                   name   id   firstname     lastname
0  MD ALEXIA DORTMINEX      1     ALEXIA    DORTMINEX
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for each row that lastname is in name with the `apply()` function and then filter your data using this mask.

As follows:

```
mask = df.apply(lambda x: x['lastname'] in x['name'], axis=1)
df = df[mask]
```

This will Output:

```
                   name   id   firstname     lastname
0  MD ALEXIA DORTMINEX      1     ALEXIA    DORTMINEX
```